# R Project Error

Tags: r, variables, graph, filenames, assign

Hi I am working on a project now, and it keeps saying error. Here is what I have so far:

```
data1 <- read.table("C:/Users/C. Pressley/Documents/Student Pair.txt", header=T)

attach(data1)
names(data1)
# [1] "Student.Pair"             "Standard.Teaching.Method" "New.Teaching.Method"     
dim(data1)
# [1] 40  3
data1[[2]]
# [1]  51  72  85  51  73  72  65  72  72  95  70  60  57  48  74  63  82  57  87  65  48  97  61  83  88  89  82  44  75  69  69  79  83  76  86  67 100  95  79  78
data1[[3]]
# [1]  67  90  82  63  76  73  78  94  85 100  80  72 100  58  89  97  88  45  81  99  69  70  47  73 100  96  99  52  74  96  84 100  84  72  97  65 100  70  83  79

help(t.test)
starting httpd help server ... done
?t.test

boxplot(data1)

plot(data1)

abline(a=0, b=1)

# Ho: Mean difference in SBP is 0
# two-sided test

t.test(a,b, paired=TRUE)
# Error in t.test(a, b, paired = TRUE) : object 'a' not found
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. When you called `t.test()`, you gave it an object that didn't exist. There is no `a` in your environment.

Comment: So, what should I call it?

Comment: Anything in `names(data1)`.

Comment: I'm trying to create a paired t test.

Comment: When you say anything in names(data1), what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no variable called `a`in your environment. And also there is no variable called `b` in your environment.
As we don't know what the aims of those functions are, we only can suppose. But you have to call the functions with the right and existing parameters. I only can suppose you meant something like this:

```
t.test(a=data1[[2]], b=data1[[3]], paired=TRUE)
```

or maybe this:

```
t.test(data1[[2]], data1[[3]], paired=TRUE)
```

Comment: OK, I'll try that. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: The second choice worked. Thank you so much. You really helped me out.

Comment: This was just guessing as you don't provide enough information. And it seems you are only guessing too. Please get information about how to call a function, what arguments are necessary, etc. and then write your code.